# Different css in wordpress view

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am building a wordpress theme for my project. I have created header with navigation. But problem I am facing is when i view website with admin login css is not working. But when i logout css is working

**Image with admin view:**
[image: Image with admin view]

**Non admin view:**
[image: Non admin view]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! please try to be more specific and show some search or some trials that you have made I recommend to read [ask],
at least you have to post your code to allow community to help out!

Comment: Please post your header.php and your index.php code

Comment: I solved it. It was an error of cache. I just cleared the cache and it works.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your config.php file and see if it works:

```
define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
```

This can sometimes fix this issue. If not, just remove it from the config.php again.